# Issue with carriage return characters while exporting from snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While exporting data from snowflake to csv file, if any column values is having carriage return then its getting split into two lines.

Comment: Can you provide more details of how you're exporting? Is it via code (like Python), the web UI, or other?

Comment: Sounds like Snowflake is exporting the data correctly. It's the program you open the file with (text editor?) that shows it on a new line... which is also correct. What exactly is the issue with having it on a separate line?

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is to escape the newline characters like this `select replace('foo\nbar', '\n', '\\n');`